# Horizontal align of 3 paragraphs inside 3 different divs

Tags: html, css, alignment

I can't use float because they aren't wrapped together. That's how it looks like:
[image: Click Here to see the mockup . A verbal explanation would be too clumsy]

Comment: Have you tried using a fixed height for the elements above the <p> tags? The easiest thing to do in my opinion is to put the first 2 elements in a container and set a fixed height to it.

Comment: Please add your relevant code!

Comment: Can you use Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: @FerSalas I tend to agree with your suggestion as a pure CSS approach, however max-height or height it will raise the problem of handling overflow.

Comment: @DarrenS Yup, I totally agree with you. I approached it as pure CSS.

Comment: The height of the parents is the same or not ?

Comment: The height of the paragraphs are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option that you can use, if height of the bottom p is fixed

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px 20px 100px 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
      <p>Other Stuff</p>
      <p class="bottom">Bootom</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <p>Other Stuff</p>
      <p>Other Stuff</p>
      <p>Other Stuff</p>
      <p>Other Stuff</p>
      <p class="bottom">Bootom</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <p>Other Stuff</p>
      <p>Other Stuff</p>
      <p class="bottom">Bootom</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your divs to `position: relative` then you can set your `<p>` tags to `position:absolute` then give it a percentage from the bottom to fit your needs.

Code and Demo:

```
<div class="div1">
   <p>I'm some random text</p>
</div>
<div class="div2">
   <p>I'm some random text</p>
</div>
<div class="div3">
   <p>I'm some random text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
}

.div1{
   border: 2px solid red;
   height: 200px;
   width: 150px;
}

.div2{
   border: 2px solid green;
   height: 200px;
   width: 150px;
}

.div3{
   border: 2px solid blue;
   height: 200px;
   width: 150px;
}

p{
   position: absolute;
   left: 4%;
   bottom: 10%;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/BoGaEa)

Comment: Thanks fot the answer. But actually the paragraphs height are not the same, so setting the same margin from the bottom won't help because I want to align them from the top. (and margin from the top is not helping because there is a different content above each one)